# Which country should be next on the list?

Tags: pattern, geography

I have constructed the following list of independent countries according to a secret pattern:

1. Belgium
2. Mexico
3. Liechtenstein
4. Ivory Coast
5. Ethiopia
6. United Kingdom
7. Philippines
8. ????????

Which country should go into position 8 on the list?
Which country would be a good candidate for position 12?
What is the secret pattern?

> **Hint:** 
>   Although this is a list, there also is an important binary pattern behind it. It all boils down to being "in" or being "out".
>   Who is **IN**? Who is **OUT**?

Comment: I'm going to guess #8 and #12 are both in the northwest hemisphere. From the CIA world factbook: Belgium (50 50 N, 4 00 E), Mexico (23 00 N, 102 00 W), Liechtenstein (47 16 N, 9 32 E), Ivory Coast (8 00 N, 5 00 W), Ethiopia (8 00 N, 38 00 E), United Kingdom (54 00 N, 2 00 W), Philippines (13 00 N, 122 00 E).

Comment: belgium is 7, mexico is 6, liechtenstein is 13. May be starting point.

Comment: What do those numbers mean though?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The pattern is :

> `i/I = 1` and `o/O = 0`. Just take the i's and o's from the country name and using their respective values 1 and 0, calculate the equivalent decimal values.

Examples :

> Belg**i**um -> 1 
>  Mex**i**c**o** -> 10 
>  L**i**echtenste**i**n -> 11 
>  **I**v**o**ry C**o**ast -> 100 
>  Eth**io**p**i**a -> 101 
>  Un**i**ted K**i**ngd**o**m -> 110 
>  Ph**i**l**i**pp**i**nes -> 111

The countries at 8th and 12th position can be :

> 8(1000) -> [Republ**i**c **o**f the C**o**ng**o**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_the_Congo)
>  12(1100) -> [Tr**i**n**i**dad and T**o**bag**o**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinidad_and_Tobago)